# What is the best way to slice CHUNKS of wood?

Tags: technique

[image]

Here is a photo of the floor I plan to install in my barn house. I have a great source for the wood, but it is all in "chunks" that are approximately 9"x11"x14". My (old) table saw blade doesn't raise high enough to easily cut even halfway through, my 12" miter saw won't accommodate them, I don't have a band saw (but might have to buy or borrow one), and I can't cut consistently enough with a chain saw. Is there an option I'm overlooking?

Comment: I noticed that you did not include handsaws.  Consider how large your sawing arm will be when you are done. ;)

Comment: Maybe contact a local mill, and see if they can resaw the wood for you? Otherwise, I'd guess that the only (safe) way of doing it is to buy/rent/borrow a larger bandsaw, and be prepared to eat a few blades.

Comment: Slightly OT, but that's going to be a _gorgeous_ floor!

Comment: I'm not going to try to put an alternate Answer to @rob's because it covers so many good options, but if it were me I'd do all the rip cuts first which would make the cross-cutting a lot more straightforward. You don't mention the species of wood you have, as long as it's not something like ironwood you could probably reasonably do the ripping with a quality old rip saw, and the pieces you end up with should be thin enough in one direction to cut with your table saw. You could also do this the opposite way, but rip cuts require much less effort than sawing across the grain.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are several options that come to mind:

1. Cut smaller pieces
2. Get a bandsaw with resaw capacity of at least 9" (many 14" or larger bandsaws either come stock with 11-12" resaw capacity, or can be upgraded with a riser block)
3. Use a saw with a significantly larger circular blade
4. Cut as deep as you can on both sides, then finish the job with a hand saw
5. Use a chainsaw mill (aka Alaska mill)--basically a guide for your chainsaw. It will require a fair amount of cleanup but it will be much less than if you make the cuts freehand
6. Have someone else with larger or more appropriate equipment cut the pieces for you--either hire a sawmill or make a new friend, perhaps someone in a local woodworking club.

As Ashlar semi-jokingly noted in a comment, you could use a handsaw exclusively, but that would not be a fast or easy task, especially if you want to crosscut the pieces as illustrated in the picture.

Comment: With a friend, spouse, relative, etc, a bucksaw could make quick work if we keep with the hand-power versus horsepower theme.